# find an ODE for the travelling-wave solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find an ordinary differential equation for the travelling-wave solution 
$$\hat{u}(\xi)=\hat{u}(x-b\cdot t)=u(x,t)$$
of
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial  x^2} - u(1-u)(a-u).$$

Draw a phase plane for $\hat{u}$ and investigate when a solution exists subject to the conditions
$$\lim_{\xi \to \infty} \hat{u}(\xi) \to 1$$
and
$$\lim_{\xi \to -\infty} \hat{u}(\xi) \to a.$$

Comment: I think this is discussed in Joel Smoller's book.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
\xi=x-bt,
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\xi=1,\;\frac{d}{dt}\xi=-b,
$$

$$
u_x=u_\xi \xi_x=u_\xi,\;\; u_t=u_\xi \xi_t=-u_\xi b.
$$
In the same manner you obtain the second derivative of $u$. Thus you obtain a second order ODE, right? In particular, you have
$$
-bu'=u''+u(1-u)(a-u).
$$
This can be written as
$$
u'=v
$$
$$
v'=-u(1-u)(a-u)-bv\;\;(=u'')
$$
Notice that $(u,v)=(0,0),(1,0)$ and $(a,0)$ are equilibrium points for the ODE. You can plot the phase portrait. Now you need to obtain $b$ such that there exists a trajectory leaving $a$ and entering into 1. I hope this can help you.